# StackExchangePy: Python3 wrapper for StackExchange API

Tags: library, python

[image: StackExchangePy Logo]

### About

StackExchangePy is another python package for StackExchange API, written in python3.

#### License

The package is under [**GPL3**](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html) license.

#### Download

To install it, type `pip3 install stackexchangepy` in your cli.

### Contact

For bugs, or questions, use the [**github**](https://bitbucket.org/mon3ita/stackexchangepy/src/master/) page of the library.

### Code

The code and the documentation of the library can be seen in [**github**](https://bitbucket.org/mon3ita/stackexchangepy/src/master/)

Comment: It seems this repo was relocated to Bitbucket: https://bitbucket.org/mon3ita/stackexchangepy/src/master/

Comment: Unfortunately, the Bitbucket link only has limited functionality (and even that requires you to enable JavaScript). The documentation link in the README is another 404; similarly, the code contains doc strings which link to this now-defunct location. By and large, this seems unmaintained and undocumented.